# PHP array to excel including hyperlink using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How will convert array to excel using PHPexcell. Its a mixed array few values are hyperlink few are dates and string. 
Thanks in advance. For below array using setCellValue and getHyperlink()->setUrl works fine But i want directly from array($array) to exce  `$array = array(
0 => array('product_name' => 'mobile', 'description' => 'Mobile Details', 'add_date' => '10-12-2015',
 'details_link' => array('lable' => 'details_link',
 'link' => 'www.example.com/mobiledetails.php')),
 1 => array('product_name' => 'Computer', 'description' => 'Computer Details', 'add_date' => '10-01-2015',
 'details_link' => array('lable' => 'details_link',
 'link' => 'www.example.com/computerdetails.php')));`

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Post some code what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHPExcel's `fromArray()` method, with the [Advanced Value Binder](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#using-value-binders-to-facilitate-data-entry); that should cover most variations, although you may need to extend the Advanced Value Binder with a custom binder to handle hyperlinks.